# Why FireDac ODBC driver won't connect to Sybase 9 on release mode from Delphi 10.01 Berlin?

Tags: delphi, sybase, delphi-10.1-berlin, firedac

Can't figure where a connection behavior is coming from, `Delphi 10.1 Berlin` or `Firedac`.

I have to Modify `VendorLib` depending on a system configuration:

`Sybase9`:

```
FDPhysASADriverLink.VendorLib :=ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Bde\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 9\win32\dbodbc9.dll';
```

or `Sybase16`:

```
FDPhysASADriverLink.VendorLib := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Bde\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 16\bin32\dbodbc16.dll';
```

Running from Delphi the  connection works fine, release or debug mode, S9 or S16.

Out from Delphi, by clicking on `exe` file:

if the project is compiled on debug mode also works fine.

The problem comes when the project is compiled on Release Mode and Sybase9, then i got this connection error:

```
[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Anywhere]Communication error.
```

So I've turned  Sybase9 instance off, then i got:

```
[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Anywhere]Specified database not found.
```

I've searched everywhere on project option, tried creating the connection component on running time, same behavior.

Printed out propertyes from `FDPhysASADriverLink`

```
Database=SYSOP
User_Name=DBA
Password=XXXXXXX
OSAuthent=No
ODBCAdvanced=AutoStop=Yes;Delphi=Yes
DriverID=ASA
Server=SYSOP_013
Compress=No
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem found:

We had to add `CommLinks` on `ODBCAdvanced` and specify `TCDIP` as a default protocol;

```
Database=SYSOP
User_Name=DBA
Password=XXXXXXX
OSAuthent=No
ODBCAdvanced=AutoStop=Yes;Delphi=Yes;CommLinks=TCPIP
DriverID=ASA
Server=SYSOP_013
Compress=No
```